# Ramsey model with government

Tags: macroeconomics, government-spending, ramsey

I have a problem with an introduction a government to Ramsey model. For example, there is a capital income tax and government returns the revenue from this tax through lump-sum transfers. What will happen when government raises tax rate? What will this look like in a phase diagram when rate of growth of technical progress and growth of population is zero? How will consumption and capital change over time?